Ubuntu display doesn't recover after locking screen with HDMI connection
Problem:
When I lock my screen using the OS key + L shortcut while connected to an external display via HDMI, I can't get the display to show up again afterwards. The screen remains blank no matter what I do.
What I've tried:
Disconnecting and reconnecting the HDMI cable
Waiting for an extended period
Pressing various key combinations
Current workaround:
The only solution I've found is to force restart the system, which is inconvenient and disruptive to my workflow.
System details:
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (64-bit)
Graphics card:
> sudo lshw -C display
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: GA103M [GeForce RTX 3080 Ti Laptop GPU]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: /dev/fb0
version: a1
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=2560x1600 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1600
resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:640-63f irq:236 memory:6f000000-6fffffff memory:6000000000-63ffffffff memory:6400000000-6401ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:70080000-700fffff
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Alder Lake-P GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
logical name: /dev/fb0
version: 0c
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=2560,1600
resources: iomemory:640-63f iomemory:400-3ff irq:235 memory:642f000000-642fffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
> xrandr | grep " connected"
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 393mm

Which nvidia driver do you have installed?

555.58.02 is the version

Let me rephrase. Are you using the open source driver or the proprietary binary driver? [Edit] your question instead of a temporary comment

How do i know whether it's proprietary or the open source one? If I installed it with ubuntu-drivers, which is the only driver related thing I did, it's the open source one?

I assume you knew, as a Linux user, on how to check something like that.

No I don't....,
